# Using Tkinter, how can I post the same image twice

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import urllib, io
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import Tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x800+20+20")

im=[]
t1=[]
z1=[]
x=var=0


def Search():

    global t1
    global var

    var = IntVar()
    show = "http://blog.acorn-is.com/wp-content/uploads/apple-full2.jpg"  #random google image
    fd = urllib.urlopen(show)
    imgFile = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
    im.append (ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgFile)))
    image = Label(root, image = im[0])

    t1.append(image)  
    z1.append(image)
    #both t1 and z1 should contain the image..

    r1 = Checkbutton(root, variable=var, command=Queue)
    r1.place(bordermode=INSIDE, x=0, y=90)


def Queue():

    if (var.get() == 1):
            z1[0].place(bordermode=INSIDE, x=0, y=300)   #x=0
            t1[0].place(bordermode=INSIDE, x=550, y=300) #x=550



tx1 = StringVar()
b1 = Button(root, text="Search", command=Search, width="20")
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

example code above. you'll notice in the Search function, that both t1 and z1 are appending the image to their own list but when i "place" z1 and t1, the image shows only once - only the second image shows. how can i get it to display the same image twice?

Answer (score 0):

See the changes below. This will make it work !

```
import urllib, io
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import Tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x800+20+20")

im=[]
t1=[]
z1=[]
x=var=0


def Search():

    global t1
    global var

    var = IntVar()
    show = "http://blog.acorn-is.com/wp-content/uploads/apple-full2.jpg"  #random google image
    fd = urllib.urlopen(show)
    imgFile = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
    im.append (ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgFile)))
    image = Label(root, image = im[0])

    t1.append(image)

    # New added line
    image = Label(root, image = im[0])

    z1.append(image)
    #both t1 and z1 should contain the image..

    r1 = Checkbutton(root, variable=var, command=Queue)
    r1.place(bordermode=INSIDE, x=0, y=90)


def Queue():

    if (var.get() == 1):
            z1[0].place(bordermode=INSIDE, x=0, y=300)   #x=0
            t1[0].place(bordermode=INSIDE, x=550, y=300) #x=550



tx1 = StringVar()
b1 = Button(root, text="Search", command=Search, width="20")
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```